# Next element in a list

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have a function in Haskell which returns me the successor of a card. I know how to access the card, using list comprehension, but not quite sure how to get the next card, so pos+1. Here is my code:

```
pCard :: Card->Deck->Card
pCard (K,C) _ = (A,S) --exception for last card
pCard crd pck = head [p | (pos,p) <- (zip [0..51] pck), crd==p]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use `dropWhile (/= crd) pck` to remove all the cards from the beginning until your card is found. Then, the first card remaining is `crd`. The one after that is the one you want.

Still, if `pck` is a deck in a *standard order*, looping over the whole deck to find the next card seems to be quite inefficient.

Comment: What about finding the predecessor. That one worked!

Comment: Do the counterpart.  `last $ takeWhile (/= crd) pck`

Answer (score 3):

You can make you your `Card` type instantiate the [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) typeclass by `deriving Enum`, then use the [`succ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ) function to get the successor card.
Note that passing the last card of the deck to `succ` will result in a runtime error, though it looks like your first `pCard` function body will account for that.

I just noticed that your `Card` type appears to be a tuple; I'm guessing you defined `Card` using the `type` keyword? In which case the solution I proposed above won't work without using GHC extensions.